# Messy output in lyx

Tags: lyx

When I try to convert document to pdfs I get a messy output where the paragraphs don't begin in same place. e.g (decline the content in hebrew): [image]

as you can see each of the lines begin in different place. How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like it isn't doing RTL typesetting.  I'm not familiar with it very much, but hopefully pointing this out will help others.  (Some relevant packages: `bidi`, `polyglossia` (or `babel` if you're using plain (La)TeX).  A neat (but ancient) tutorial that uses LyX: http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/Pubs/eutupon.pdf

Comment: I would think that the first and fourth line are simply indented with the standard paragraph indentation. The second line is probably pushed right because a line break isn't added inside the equation. Normally, line breaks can occur within inline math, so information about how you wrote that equation could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 'mess' actually comes from the second line I think, which is too long, and pokes into the right margin a bit. The reason it becomes too long is that TeX is unable to find a place to break the equation. Inline math can normally break across lines, so without knowing exactly how you created that equation, it is hard (for me at least) to give any specific advice. You could consider making it a displayed equation instead, by right clicking and choosing *Displayed Formula*, which will place the equation in a separate paragraph.

The first and fourth line I would think are indented slightly because they are at the start of a paragraph, and the default behaviour for TeX is to separate paragraphs by indenting the first line. If you want to change this, go to Document --> Settings --> Text layout. Here you have the choice of separating paragraphs with either an indent of specified length, or a vertical gap. If you define a vertical gap, then the indent is set to zero.

When you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in LyX a new paragraph is started.